How to write the path in python to access a folder from windows desktop
C:\Users\jisha>cd \Desktop\ExerciseFiles\   --- this is the command i have given in command prompt in Windows.
The system cannot find the path specified.    ----this is the error message.
I want to access the ExerciseFiles folder in the desktop. How to get the path?
I tried to get a folder in my desktop and it is named as ExerciseFiles. Is anyone know how to get the path

When the computer tells you a file doesn’t exist, it’s nearly always right. A typical beginner mistake is supplying the wrong directory name. If you are a Windows user, dragging the file to a CMD window will reveal its correct path; similar mechanisms nre often available in other GUIs, too.

If you are trying to reach a folder from a cmd then command would be:
cd C:\Users\jisha\Desktop\ExerciseFiles

If you are trying to run cmd command from python then it goes like this
import os
os.system('cd C:\Users\jisha\Desktop\ExerciseFiles')


I would replace the use of os.system with os.chdir

The simple answer to make this work is removing the starting \
i.e. cd Desktop\ExerciseFiles
The core problem is that when you specify \Desktop\ instead of looking relative to your position (C:\Users\jisha), it uses the top level (C:) so it looks for C:\Desktop which doesnt exist
